# Extending behaviour according to combinations of conditions

Tags: python, algebra

I'm writing some code in python that roughly approximates to the following:

```
vals = [3, 4]
constraints = [5, 10]

def foo(val, constraint):
    return val <= constraint

def bar(x, y):
    # do stuff such as:
    print(x, y)

def baz(val):
    # transform val, such as by doing: 
    new_val = (val * 20 - 5) ** 2
    return new_val

bar(*vals)
if foo(vals[0], constraints[0]):
    bar(vals[0], baz(vals[1]))
if foo(vals[1], constraints[1]):
    bar(baz(vals[0]), vals[1])
if foo(vals[0], constraints[0]) and foo(vals[1], constraints[1]):
    bar(baz(vals[0]), baz(vals[1]))
```

I recognize that this is an algebraic relationship, so it feels like there should be a much more concise way to represent this in code.

Let's say that a `True` returned by `foo` on index 0 is `A`, and `True` returned by `foo` on index 1 is `B`. The operation applied when `A` is true is `a`, and likewise `B`'s is `b`. Any other result is `_`. The set of values to be generated would be:

```
  |   _    |    A   |    B   |
-----------------------------
_ |  x,  y |  x,  y |  x,  y |
  |        | ax,  y |  x, by |
-----------------------------
  |  x,  y |  x,  y |  x,  y |
A | ax,  y | ax,  y |  x, by |
  |        |        | ax, by |
-----------------------------
  |  x,  y |  x,  y |  x, y  |
B |  x, by | ax,  y |  x, by |
  |        | ax, by |        |
```

Is there a concise (and preferably general) way to generate these values so that they can later be `map`ped or iterated?

Comment: What are `bar` and `baz` in this context?

Comment: @James `bar` is a function with side effects not related to the code shown. `baz` is a transformation on its input value, such as addition, multiplication, or any other operation that preserves type.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I'm not sure what's meant when you say you want a "concise way to represent this in code".  If you'd like to generalize those functions, you could use this:

```
def foo(val, constraint):
    return val <= constraint

def bar(x, y):
    print x, y

def baz(val):
    return (val * 20 - 5) ** 2

def foobar(a, b)
    if a <= b:
        print a, b

def barbaz(a, b, c)
    if b <= c:
        print baz(a), b

def bazfoo(a, b, c, d)
    if a <= b and c <= d:
        print baz(a), baz(c)

vals = [3, 4]
constraints = [5, 10]

bar(*vals)

foobar(vals[0], constraints[0])
barbaz(vals[0], vals[1], constraints[1])
bazfoo(vals[0], constraints[0], vals[1], constraints[1])
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a very general solution to the problem. The amount of explicit coding required to make `foobar`, `barbaz`, and `bazfoo` defeats the purpose of refactoring the `if` statements. Consider the simplified version: `if a: f1(); if b: f2(); if a and b: f3()`. Theoretically, it could be refactored to `if a: f1(); elif b: f2(); anyif: f3()`. I'm wondering if python has an in-built way to do this (as there are cases where the `if`s may be more long-winded)

Comment: @Aaron2468 Got it.  I don't think I understand the problem.